# Is it male...? / Is it a male...?

Tags: articles

Which question is idiomatic if we talk about animals? If both versions are correct, could you explain why "a" can be omitted. Male & female are countable nouns in the questions (not adjectives), right?

> **Is it** male or female?

> **Is it a** male or female?

Comment: Your usage is as *adjective* in the first example and *noun* in the second, where I would try to use an appropriate one, if it exists: "Is it a bull or a cow?" Also stag/hind, cock/hen etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically valid.

"Male" and "female" can be used as either nouns or adjectives.

As a noun, one might say, for example, "Three males entered the room."

As an adjective, one could say, "Male peacocks have fancy tails." Note "male" here is an adjective modifying "peacock".

So you could say, "Is it a male?", using male as a noun. Or you could say, "Is it male?", using male as an adjective.

Comment: What version do you usually use if you want to know the gender of the dog?

Comment: If I have a guess, I usually use the noun. "Is it a male?" But if I don't have a guess and want to mention both possibilities, I use the adjective. "Is it male or female?" I can't give a good reason for why I am inconsistent like this. The two are pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: For a pet dog:  "Is it a boy or girl?"  We often refer to pets as  "good boy" etc

Comment: Could you please tell me how it is natural to say following: "It seems it is a female/girl". Or maybe, "It looks like a female/girl". Are these answers idiomatic? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Sergey: "Female" is clinical; using "a female" to refer to a *human* may be perceived as offensive in some contexts (prefer "a woman/girl" depending on age - an adult human is *never* a "girl"). But when talking about animals, "girl" is mildly anthropomorphizing and would be more common with pets than with e.g. lab or farm animals.

Comment: @Kevin Well, lots of adult women refer to themselves as "girls". For example, this woman, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxNt7__jPpU, calls herself a "50 year old farm girl". There was a popular TV show in the 1980s about a group of women in their 60s or so that was called "The Golden Girls". Etc.

Comment: @Sergey Both are valid and idiomatic. I agree with Kevin that, using "boy" or "girl" to refer to something other than a human is not literally correct; it is talking about a non-human as if it was human. We sometimes do this with pets but rarely with farm animals or wild animals.

Comment: @Jay: You can call *yourself* a "girl/boy," and if someone explicitly wants to be called that, it's OK to do so. But if you, apropos of nothing, call a woman a "girl," it will be seen as demeaning.

Comment: @kevin So some women want to be called "girls", but if you call a woman a "girl" it's always demeaning? That doesn't make sense. If you want to say that a man shouldn't call a woman a "girl" because she MIGHT take it as demeaning, fair enough. Some women take it as demeaning, some take it as a compliment (implying she looks young and pretty), and I'd guess most don't really car. Just like, if someone casually referred to me as "that boy over there", I can't imagine I'd care. If someone said to me, "Hey boy! Do what I tell you!" I'd be insulted.

Comment: No less confusing, but I usually ask, "Is it a he or a she?"